# Multiples modelos en una vista ASP NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, model-view-controller

Hola amigos sigo atorado con esto, alguien me pueda hechar una mano ...
Este es mi error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son mis modelos y mi htmlCs

```js
//kyo es el nombre de mi vista, este es el controller
        //GET: Home/kyo
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Kyo( )
        {
            
              return View();
        }
```

Con esto estoy llamando a los modelos de los que quiero mis datos

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using PCotiza_compras.Models;


namespace PCotiza_compras.Models
{
    public class ReqCatDep
    {
        public List<PCotiza_compras.Models.Departments> Dep { get; set; }
        public List<PCotiza_compras.Models.Categories> Cat { get; set; }
        public List<PCotiza_compras.Models.Requests> Req { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Y esta es mi vista :

```html
@model PCotiza_compras.Models.ReqCatDep

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Kyo";
}


<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <td>

      @foreach (var item in Model.Cat)
      {
          <tr>
              @item.Name
          </tr>
          <tr>
              @item.Description
          </tr>
      }

     
  </td>

</div>
```

Gracias a todos :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feliz tarde asi como usas razor para hacer el foreach tambien puedes hacer un if para verificar antes de recorrer si tu objeto es nulo

```html
@model PCotiza_compras.Models.ReqCatDep

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Kyo";
}


<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <td>
      @if(Model != null && Model.Cat != null)
      {
        @foreach (var item in Model.Cat)
        {
            <tr>
                @item.Name
            </tr>
            <tr>
                @item.Description
            </tr>
        }
      }     
  </td>

</div>
```

de estas forma no tendras ese error mas sin embargo debe llenar la lista en el controlador

Comment: Hola todos los ejemplos que he encontrado llenan la lista manualmente desde el controlador como dices, me encuentra en la situación de que debo jalar esos objetos desde una base de datos, he intentado hace un await db.Departments.ToList pero no he tenido éxito, algún consejo?

Comment: btw con lo que me dijiste el error ahora me parece aquí: @if (Model.Cat != null)

Comment: entiendo creo el mismo Model es nulo tambien añadelo antes y enlazalo con && algo asi... @if (Model != null &&  Model.Cat != null)

Comment: Hola funcionó super pero mis modelos no me dan datos de respuesta u.u

Comment: como dicen los demas no haz colocado el modelo en el ActionResult en el  return View(); entre los parentesis va el modelo eso seria todo lo que te mostre solo son validaciones en caso que el modelo sea nulo

Answer (score 2):

Brother, veo que tienes varios problemas, vamos a solucionarlos:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Kyo( )
{
    //Aqui te hace falta tu modelo.
    var modelo = llamas a tu base de datos, a la tabla que deseas.
    modelo.cat = lista de elementos
    return View(modelo);
}
```

Revisa este código: https://github.com/fredyfx/UPAOnetStackOverflowES-ASPnetMVC tiene un proyecto sencillo de 3 capas + base de datos. El video de youtube explico a detalle cómo funciona ASPnet MVC.

Answer (score 1):

No estas pasandole el modelo a tu vista, debes hacer algo así :

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Kyo( )
    {
          // Debes crear la logica para llenar el modelo y pasarlo a la vista
          var model = LlenarReqCatDep();


          return View(model);
    }
```

Obvio que para que tu codigo sea de la mejor calidad, debes validar que los datos requiridos por la vista estén en el modelo.

Comment: Pues he esto intentando esto para llenar la tabla pero sin mucho exito, necesito llenar la tabla con la info que hay en mi bd. Obvio lo estoy haciendo desde el model :
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Kyo()
        {

            ReqCatDep dep_list = new ReqCatDep();
            dep_list.Dep = db.Department.ToList();
            return View(dep_list.Dep);

        }

Comment: Eduardo, primero tenemos que mirar que has hecho a nivel de EntityFramework para que eso te funcione, puedes compartir tu codigo de los dbsets y el dbcontext ?

Comment: Hola Mauricio ocmo soy de lvl muy bajo no puedo postear mas que coments, pero haré mi pregunta otra vez con más info , gracias :D